# IPv6ToBigInteger

Tags: scala, bit-manipulation, ipv6, biginteger, inetaddress

I have this function which uses `InetAddress`, but the output is occasionally wrong. (example: `"::ffff:49e7:a9b2"` will give an incorrect result.)

```
def IPv6ToBigInteger(ip: String): BigInteger = {
        val i = InetAddress.getByName(ip)
        val a: Array[Byte] = i.getAddress
        new BigInteger(1, a)
    }
```

And the I also have this function

```
def IPv6ToBigInteger(ip: String): BigInteger = {
    val fragments = ip.split(":|\\.|::").filter(_.nonEmpty)
    require(fragments.length <= 8, "Bad IPv6")
    var ipNum = new BigInteger("0")
    for (i <-fragments.indices) {
        val frag2Long = new BigInteger(s"${fragments(i)}", 16)
        ipNum = frag2Long.or(ipNum.shiftLeft(16))
    }
    ipNum
}
```

which appears to have a parsing error because it gives the wrong output unless it is in `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0` format, but is an based on my IPv4ToLong function:

```
def IPv4ToLong(ip: String): Long = {
        val fragments = ip.split('.')
        var ipNum = 0L
        for (i <- fragments.indices) {
            val frag2Long = fragments(i).toLong
            ipNum = frag2Long | ipNum << 8L
        }
        ipNum
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting challenge: transform IP address strings into `BigInt` values, allowing for all legal IPv6 address forms.

Here's my try.

```
import scala.util.Try

def iPv62BigInt(ip: String): Try[BigInt] = Try{
  val fill = ":0:" * (8 - ip.split("[:.]").count(_.nonEmpty))
  val fullArr =
    raw"((?<=\.)(\d+)|(\d+)(?=\.))".r
      .replaceAllIn(ip, _.group(1).toInt.toHexString)
      .replace("::", fill)
      .split("[:.]")
      .collect{case s if s.nonEmpty => s"000$s".takeRight(4)}

  if (fullArr.length == 8) BigInt(fullArr.mkString, 16)
  else throw new NumberFormatException("wrong number of elements")
}
```

This is, admittedly, a bit lenient in that it won't catch all all non-IPv6 forms, but that's not a trivial task using tools like regex.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
ipNum = frag2Long | ipNum << 8L
```

is

```
ipNum = (frag2Long | ipNum) << 8L
```

not

```
ipNum = frag2Long | (ipNum << 8L)
```

[ And please use `foldLeft` rather than `var` and `while` ]